# Connect Pipes With the Series of Manhole in Autodesk Dynamo

Tags: python, autodesk, revit

I’ve created a script that instantiated manhole on a series of points that were generated on a property line. Now I’d like to instantiate a pipe and connect its open and close end with each next manhole in the series. Would appreciate if someone suggest how do I achieve this functionality with dynamo. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the manholes are defined as pipe fittings with appropriate connectors, the pipes will connect themselves to them automatically, as illustrated by my series of articles on [creating a rolling offset](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/01/final-rolling-offset-using-pipecreate.html).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Considering your points in mind, I will try to experiment it today. Cheers!